# how to access a webcam that was symlinked by udev in opencv

Tags: c++, python, linux, opencv, video-capture

I am developing an application that requires multiple webcams.  In order to make sure that the correct webcam is used for each part of the application, I created some udev rules that SYMLINK the webcam to a specific name, depending on the serial number.

This works great, and I can access the camera by that name using VLC and a variety of other applications.

But when I try to access the camera by that name (or the non-syminked name given by linux) using OpenCV and python, I can't read a frame from the camera and my program hangs.  The camera is opened successfully.  I've created a sample application in C++ to test if it was perhaps a python/opencv related bug, but the same thing happens in C++ too.

Here is my C++ test application that doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap("/dev/my_custom_name");
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;

    cout << "Opened..." << endl;

    Mat img;
    namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Trying..." << endl;
        cap >> img;
        cout << "Got" << endl;
        imshow("video capture", img);
        if (waitKey(10) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the `Opened...` and `Trying...` messages, but not the `Got` message.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

(This is all on linux btw).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  When I opened the capture in VLC, I noticed that it preixed the filename with `v4l2://`.  When I did the same in my application, it worked!

So to reference above, `"/dev/my_custom_name"` should become `"v4l2:///dev/my_custom_name"`.